# High-level thread usage for async working with devices

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, future

I need to work with several devices in my program, and I want this to be done on high-level thread API.
Usually a communication with a device consists of transmit a command and receive an answer (via Sockets, Serial port, etc.).

The main problem is that communication with devices could not be placed in a GUI (main) thread because no device responds instantly.

Now I decide to make all the communications with devices [on asynchronous operations](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/368026/architecture-for-working-with-several-devices), for example using [`std::async`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) and [`std::future`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future) My main framework, ([Qt 5](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/)), has its own "async" - [`QtConcurrent::run()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrent.html#run), [`QFuture`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfuture.html#details), etc., but it also doesn't provide thread selection. The next problem is that I shall to work with a selected device in only one additional thread always,

because:

1. I don't want to make each of devices' class thread-safe, and using alone thread can decide this, as it seems to me.
2. I don't want to think about thread-safety of a realization of different io interfaces (for example, [Serial port in Qt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qserialport.html#details) cannot be opened in more than one thread, but it is just details).

> **Note:** The serial port is always opened with exclusive access (that is, no other process or thread can access an already opened serial port).

3. I want, if possible, use high-level threading API, and don't want to work with low-level thread primitives.
4. Don't want to move all the device objects into one another thread, because it will be just one large "God" wrapper.

I see the next options:

1. Find a way to run all necessary asynchronous operations in a target specific thread (**preferably**).
2. Look at other similar concepts, like Tasks
3. Write my own "asyncable" thread class

   Additional note: I don't want to use event-driven-only logic.

What about I think now (simplified).
**Header:**

```
#include <future>
using namespace std; //

struct TStatus
{
    bool health;
};

class AsyncDevice
{
public:
    AsyncDevice(IODevice* ioDevice);
    future<TStatus> getHealthStatus();

private:
    TStatus get_health_impl();

private:
    IODevice*       m_ioDevice;
    EventHandler*   m_eventHandler; // Observer to notify
};
```

**CPP:**

```
future<TStatus> AsyncDevice::getHealthStatus()
{
    // ** Here I cannot use choose one specified thread ***
    future<TStatus> ret = async(launch::async, 
        &AsyncDevice::get_health_impl, this);

    return ret;
}

TStatus AsyncDevice::get_health_impl()
{
    writeDeviceCmd();
    waitForBytesWritten();

    // Here it is easy and simply to wait, read and check an answer
    TStatus status;

    int timeout = 500;
    if (waitForReadyRead(timeout))
    {
        status = readDeviceAnswer();
    }
    else
    {
        status.health = false;
    }

    m_eventHandler->onHealthStatus(status); // Notify observer
    return status;
}
```

**My main question:**
what is the best solution for problems of this kind? Could you explain it?

Comment: For me, multi-threading is the choice for exploiting all CPU cores for things which need much/most computational power. But, it's not necessary when things shall be done interleaved (or pseudo concurrent). For this, other techniques exist which were well established even before multi-threading became popular: 1. event driven processing (Qt is essentially based  on this). 2. objects with states. For this, an object (managing a certain task which has to be continued later) just stores its current state in a member and hence can properly resume when event handlers are called for further progress.

Comment: @Scheff but an event-driven exchange with a device, which has many commands and many possible answers, looks too complicated. What if I want to receive an answer in the same place where a request was sent?

Comment: You might wanna have a look at `boost::asio`. The documentation is not the greatest out there, but once you get the idea, it's amazing what you can achieve with a single thread. There is plenty of project out there using it. The origin is high frequenncy trading. I am in no way related to the project.

Comment: If you have the socket descriptor(s) to hand then you might be able to use `QAbstractSocket` and [`QAbstractSocket::setSocketDescriptor`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#setSocketDescriptor).  That way you can avoid explicit threading in your own code whilst making use of the various signals from the `QAbstractSocket` to do whatever is necessary.

Comment: @G.M. I have edited my question

Comment: You should only go for threading if you have blocking operations (be it IO or number crunching), or if you are doing something very latency sensitive. For sockets or serial port, you should use the existing Qt classes and not roll your own! If you need to roll your own for some purpose, look how the existing classes are implemented, and do it the same way. Also mixing Qt and boost::asio is probably not wise choice, if I may draw any conclusions from the level of your question.

Comment: @hyde of course I use existing Qt classes for IO, and not going to use boost at the same time. But my main question is about a good solution for threads, could you write your version?

Comment: @hyde also I can replace `std::future` with `QFuture`, etc.

Comment: To be honest, the code shown looks fine apart from... your use of the various `waitFor*` functions.  Instead, you should connect to the various [`QIODevice` signals](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#signals) and act on those signals as they are received -- which may involve your `AsyncDevice` emitting its own signal(s).

Answer (score 0):

You are using Qt and all IO using Qt APIs is done asynchronously. For example `QIoDevice::read` completes immediately and is none blocking. Qt signal `QIoDevice::readyRead` is triggered when there is data ready to be read and if you attach a slot to this you will be able to get at your data. This all means that you can do io in your GUI thread on qt and there is no need to spawn new threads for this.

Comment: Then I will have all answers from a device in one event, and it is not comfortable. Why I have to prefer the whole event-driven model, instead of async-wait? What is the standard name of what I want?

Comment: No. Each Device like a TCP socket or a Serial Port will have its own instance of QIoDevice. When you connect a slot, it is connected to a specific instance of the device you are using. They may all run in the same thread but each Device will have its own callbacks.

Comment: Of course I know about the signals. But if I have a TCP device with 10 command types, I want to process every Answer exactly in the place where  Request was sent

Comment: And how do you expect to demultiplex the command types? This is specific to your application and there must be done at one point.

Comment: @VladimirBershov Yeah, it can be a bit tedious, having async/await syntax would be cleaner. But there isn't such syntax really. You should probably write a separate class, which receives the individual low-level reads, and puts them together, and then emits a complete "command" when it is ready.

Comment: Well you will need to wait for the co-routine TS for async/await